# remove certain legend variables and legend values from ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

suppose I'm plotting a dataframe in ggplot2 like:

```
ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, color=Species, size=Sepal.Length))
```

two related questions:

1. how can I remove a variable altogether from the legend? For example, still size the points by `Sepal.Length` but remove `Sepal.Length` from the legend altogether?
2. how can I remove just a certain value or set of values from the legend? For example, still color the points by Species as above, but in the legend only show the value for `setosa` and exclude `versicolor, virginica`?

thanks.

Comment: An answer to your first question would be `scale_size(guide = "none")`. As for the second, I don't know of an easy way to do that off the top of my head.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. As commented by joran, use `scale_size(guide = "none")`.
2. `scale_color_discrete(breaks="setosa")`

Comment: I dont understand why this answer works for this question. Could you explain how a user can know which `scale_`-function from `ggplot2` to use? And do you have a source that is useful in this regard? Your answer to use `scale_color_discrete` works in this specific case to remove legend variables, but in some others it does not.

Comment: @Leo After the first dash you can put anything that has data mapped to it (x, y, color, size in this example). After the second dash you can put continuous (for continuous variables) or discrete (for factor variables).